# How to create a list from returned odata data

Tags: c#

I have returned some odata data to a c# client using:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("testserver/WebApi/odata"); 
var container = new CourseService.Container(uri);
```

How do I convert the data into a list?

The returned data is a list of courses:

```
public partial class Course
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Guid { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a sample code for you.

```
 List<Course> CourseList = new List<Course>();
        foreach (var item in container)
        {
            Course obj = new Course();
            obj.Name = item.Name;
            obj.Description = item.Description;
            obj.Guid = item.Guid;
            CourseList.Add(obj);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! First time I've used Stackoverflow. I also had a go at working out the answer to my own question...and did this:             Uri uri = new Uri("http://testserver/WebApi/odata"); //Test server
            var container = new CourseService.Container(uri);


            var courselist = from course in container.Courses
                        select new Course() { Name = course.Name, Description = course.Description, Guid = course.Guid };

            courselist.ToList();

            List<Course> courselist1 = courselist.ToList();